# Ember.js : Click on a link with an id sends a json-request and the received data can't be displayed under the overview table

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember.js which seems to be very interesting but hard/difficult to learn cause there are so many ways to solve a programming problem.

I try to code a very simple app but don't know how...

The app show at the top in a table all customers with an id received from a json file (testin local) and on click on the id there will be a json-request to receive detailed infos to the customer.

The problem is, that I receive detailed data but can't display it in a template under the overview template...

Can some one help me...!?

Greets
Christian [from germany]

---

Here's some code-snippets I got till now...

**APP.JS**

```
App.Search = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Search.reopenClass({  
  all: function() {
    // console.log('Search.reopenClass all');
    return $.getJSON("json/kunden_suchen.json").then(function(response) {
      var items = [];
      response.Konto.forEach(function(child) {
        // console.log(child);
        var item = new App.item();
        item.set('content', child);
        item.set('nr', child.nr);
        item.set('name1', child.name1);
        item.set('name2', child.name2);
        item.set('plz', child.anschrift.plz);
        item.set('anschrift', child.anschrift);
        items.push(item);
      });
      return items;
    });
  }
});

App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // console.log('SearchRoute model');
    return App.Search.all();
  },
  events: {    
    details: function() {
      console.log('SearchRoute detail');
      return App.Details.all();
    }
  } 
});

App.Details= Ember.Object.extend();

App.Details.reopenClass({  
  all: function() {
    // console.log('Search.reopenClass all');
    // return $.getJSON("json/kunden_suchen.json").then(function(response) {
      return $.getJSON("json/customer.json").then(function(response) {
      var items = [];
      response.Konto.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child);
        var item = new App.item();
        item.set('content', child);
        item.set('nr', child.nr);
        items.push(item);
      });
      return items;
    });
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
    <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>            
          <th>Name1</th>            
          <th>nr</th>            
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each item in model}}
          <tr class="info">
            <td> {{ item.content.name1 }} </td>
            <td> {{ item.content.id}} </td>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in ember are augmented, e.g. it's prototype, so for your arrays to be binding aware and thus live updating your templates when the data asynchronously arrives you can't just use vanilla `push(...)` but `pushObject(...)` instead.

So try to change every occurrence of `push` to `pushObject`

```
...
items.pushObject(item);
...
```

Hope it helps.

Greets Alex [From Spain] :)